# removing left and right margins form my horizontal menu

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I'm using 960 grid framework for prototyping a web project.My horizontal menu has 10px margins from left and right.I know that is because I put it in container_12 wrapper but I want to make it stretch with full page width. Here is the code so-fare:

```
<div id="wraper" class="container_12">
    <header id="masthead">
        <div id="site-brand">
            <h1><a href="#">فنان ويب</a></h1>
        </div><!-- =end site-brand-->
        <div id="search-box">
            <form class="form-wrapper cf">
              <button type="submit">بحث</button>
              <input type="text" placeholder="ابحث في الموقع" required title="أدخل كلمة البحث">
            </form>   
        </div><!-- =end search-box-->
        <nav id="main-nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">الرئسية</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">دروس</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">دورات</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">عن الموقع</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">من أنا؟</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

css:

```
  #main-nav{
  background:#fff;
  float:right;
  width:100%;
  border-radius: 1px;
    }

 #main-nav ul{
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
 } 

#main-nav li{
 display:inline;
 float:right;
padding:10px 22px 10px 30px;
text-align: center;
border-left: 1px #DADADA dotted;
}
#main-nav>ul>li:last-child {
    border:none;
}

#main-nav a{
  color:#000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  display:block;
    }

#main-nav li:hover{
  color:#ffffff;
  background:#de4062;

}

#main-nav a:hover{
  color:#ffffff;
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: can you please supply your stylesheet?

Comment: what are the css styles for the div "container_12" ?

Comment: container_12 is a standard class name in 960 grid and has it own styling in separate 960.css file and I don't want to miss with it

Comment: So why don't you put your #main-nav outside of the .container_12?

Comment: because this is how I planed my code to be in this order if I did what you suggest I should put it after the <body> tag and this will ruin my styling

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code

```
#main-nav{
margin-left: 0;
margin-right: 0;
}
```

also set the padding of its parent to 0 like `padding: 0;`

Comment: the problem is #main-nav is contained in .container_12 class of 960.gs which is 960px wide and I want my horizontal menu to have the full width of the page not the container